# how to capture text from the keyboard to string

Tags: java, android, string, text

I need capture text with keyboard system to String. I show keyboard on function : `KeyboardSystem.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);`
I would like to capture text on this keyboard. It is possible ?

Comment: Please share a context in what you are developing. What programming language this is (C#)? What API/environment? Tagging your question properly will bring you more experts.

Comment: Android. My problem is that I want to capture the individual characters (specifically regional) system keypad and store them in a string.The layout does not have any EditText why I can not capture the focus because I want to do immediately to string

Comment: I'm not sure this is allowed due to security restrictions, but I could be wrong.

Comment: This problem is solve, but I have new problem. In method  dispatchKeyEvent calls Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(event.event.getDisplayLabel()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); Unfortunately toast does not display regional chars.